# Do we really 'extend' traits in scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, mixins

While learning Scala I've been scratching at understanding a particular nuance:

`trait Test`

`class Tester with Test    //#A: Throws compilation error`

`class Tester extends Test //#B: works just fine`

Now, we aren't really *extending* the trait per se (or are we?). Here are the questions I have:

1. How does extending a trait differ from extending a class? Is it just a *special* case syntax for a single trait and I just accept it as a language nuance?
2. Why is #A incorrect? Why can't we do this? Why must we *extend* the trait if there isn't any super class to inherit from?

Martin Odersky stated in a response to a [similar question](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10145.html) that it was the convention but people found it confusing. I'm not sure why that would be the case or what problems led to this decision? But here's his response:

> We had that convention early on in the design of Scala. People found
>   it confusing. That's why we changed to use always `extends'. The way I
>   see it is like this:
>
> class A extends B with C { ... }
>
> should be decomposed as:
>
> class A extends <<< B with C { ... } >>>
>
> That is, A is a class that extends the anonymous template B with C {
>   ... }. It does not matter whether that template starts with a class or
>   a trait.
>
> Another advantage of the new convention is that subclasses are not
>   affected when a class is changed to a trait or vice versa, something
>   that happens quite often and naturally.

Although I can *live with* his explanation and rewire my thinking (and see the advantage of changing a class to a trait, a mere side-effect of the design choice) I'd still like to understand this nuance more intuitively.

Comment: You might want to check how these are compiled and into  linearization. I did look into these aspects at some point but quickly lost interest as they are not relevant to my personal interests.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to ask this question at the Scala gitter channels or MLs? You may actually get a answer from the author of the language.

Comment: @pedrofurla - I did. Now that I think of it again my guess is that the presence of `super` in some trait must "terminate" somewhere and the safest spot is in a class definition. If the `with` hierarchy stops at the existing class it's possible `super` calls may just not get resolved. I'm totally winging this explanation based on my (limited) understanding of this.

Comment: Note that `B with C` is actually a legal type in Scala. I can `def foo(x: B with C) = ...` and the only method is only callable on types that include both traits. So Martin's suggestion isn't just one way of looking at it; it's telling you something important about the language. `with` is a combiner; it's not just a different name for Java's `implements`.

Comment: @SethTisue - Agreed. Let's go with that. Then why is it an error to use a _combiner_ by itself? Why _extend_ the concatenation of combiners (i.e., linearization). Maybe I'm over-reading into the problem...

Comment: "why is it an error to use a combiner by itself" — the same reason that in English it isn't grammatical to say just "and A" or "A and", it only makes sense to say "A and B". as for why extend the concatenation, because that is actually the type you are extending. the meaning and the way you write it are in perfect alignment.

Comment: @SethTisue something like `class A injects B with C` would be more logical for traits and would separate inheritance (`extends`) from mixing in (`injects`) with corresponding type-checks (can't mix in a class, can't extend a partially-implemented trait), but of course it would be a redundant keyword, so I'm not proposing it actually. Besides, we would probably need to have `implements` to deal with traits that act like an interface. IMO, `extends` is a rudiment from Java's approach to OOP, so the name is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you one example where I feel that the "concept" of "extending" a `trait` actually is logical,

take a look at following code using a mix of `Structural Type` and `Self Referencing Trait`,

```
type Fooable = {
  def foo(): Unit
}


trait FooableExtra { self: Fooable =>

  def omgWeCanFoo(): Unit = {
    println("foo :: by :: FooableExtra")
    self.foo()
  }

}

class OneThingWithFoo extends FooableExtra {

  def foo(): Unit = {
    println("foo :: by :: OneThingWithFoo")
  }

  def oneThing: Unit = {}
}
```

I can not explain it in words and is more of an intuitive thing... but this is what makes me have a clear conscience whenever I write something like `class A extends TraitA`.